# Set CommandParameter to ListBoxItem selected event

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listboxitem, commandbinding

I would like to pass a CommandParameter to a Command on ListBoxItem selection but can't figure out how to do it (I'm new to mvvm & commands so it may be trivial).

I tried to do this, but the CommandParameter property seems not to be available:

```
<ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{Binding OperationsCommand}"/>
    </ListBoxItem.CommandBindings>
    <TextBlock Text="All Items"/>
</ListBoxItem>
```

Comment: Do you know you can actually bind the selected item to your viewmodel? <ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding MyItem}"/>

Comment: Indeed, that's a good idea. Thank you. Instead of passing a parameter I'll just get the currently selected item. Write this as the answer so I can mark the question as anwered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the selecteditem to your viewmodel directly and in setter for that item you can perform your operation.

```
<ListBox ItemSource="{Binding YourCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding MyItem}"/>
```

Comment: +1 Alternativly one could do this at template level with a regular command, overkill in this scenario.